# Adjust UICollectionView scrollOffset in intervals of the cell width

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a collection view as such (scrolls sideways):

[image]

When the user scrolls, I want to adjust the table so it lines up perfectly around the static square.

I decided to do this using the scrollView when it ends dragging. However it is always just a little but off or at the very end completely off.

Where are my calculations going wrong?

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

    if (![scrollView isKindOfClass:[IndexedCollectionView class]]) return;

    IndexedCollectionView *collectionView = (IndexedCollectionView *)scrollView;

    NSMutableArray *data = self.sectionsData[collectionView.index];
    int cellsCount = data.count;
    if (cellsCount==0) {
        cellsCount++;
    }

    //Adjust cells so they line up correctly
    CGPoint adjustedOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    long interval = scrollView.contentSize.width/cellsCount;
    long remainder = (long)adjustedOffset.x%interval;
    long adjustment = interval-remainder;
    adjustedOffset.x +=adjustment;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        [scrollView setContentOffset:adjustedOffset];

    }];

    NSInteger index = collectionView.index;
    self.contentOffsetDictionary[[@(index) stringValue]] = @(adjustedOffset.x);
}
```

Comment: Are you using a flow layout? If so, what are the other insets / line spacings etc. on that object? You'll probably need to take those into account also.

Comment: I am. I figured if I just took the contentSize it would account for that